# Adding self closing tags in RTF field

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

We did an upgrade from Tridion 5.3 to Tridion 2011 SP1.

In our existing content at so many place in RTF field we are using html element like `<a name="top" id="top"></a>`. When we publish component/page from tridion anchors `<a>` tags are getting converted to self closing anchor tags `<a name="top" id="top" />`. Because of this hyperlink is getting formed on entire content of RTF field, as browser is treating this tag a start tag of anchor `<a>`.  When we check page source in FireFox it says "Self-closing syntax ("/>")" used on non-void HTML element.  Ignoring the slashes and treating as a start tag.  To fix this we update the existing content to `<a name="top" id="top">&nbsp;</a>` it is working fine but not a good solution.  Any other ideas/configuration, so that it will not be converted to self closing tags.

Comment: This was already addressed in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10537656/1269175

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have a similar question about this [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10537656/creating-anchor-links-in-rich-text-fields-with-sdl-tridion-2011-sp1)

I have posted my work around there. Hope it helps.

I am not sure what kind of templates you are using, but generally I post process my output and look for any empty tags using an XSLT and the XSLT Mediator. When I find empty tags I tend to convert them to contain empty text to prvent any issues in the browsers viewing the final content.

```
<div></div> or <div/>
```

will get converted to

```
<div> </div>
```

Whilst the first examples are technically valid XML, they do (as you have discovered) break several browsers.

Comment: We are using modular templates.  RTF content is read in .Net Assembly(c#) and displayed using Dreamweaver.

Comment: Then you could write a CheckForEmptyTags() TBB using c# to parse your output and check for any empty tags like I do with my XSLT